# Angular 6: refresh route from a partial component

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, local-storage, partial

I have an app of courses in English and French. I want to make a header for languages dropdown in another component that'll appear in all the pages of the program. When a user change the language in the header I want this things to happen:

1. The frontend call the backend and change language preference for the user so next time he'll enter he'll see the courses in the language he choose
2. that no matter where, the route'll change to course-list page and load the courses with the updated preference.

For now, it's only work if I refresh the page and not immediately.
When I wrote the language button in every component I have it worked.

**EDIT:** it's working in all pages except for course-list, probably because we are inside this component already so we don't call the function getCoursesByLanguage (when we are on other components, I user router.navigate to course-list component which trigger the getCoursesByLanguage). How I make it work on course-list page?

this is the relevant code:

**app.component.html**

```html
<div class='container-fluid' id='main'>
      <lg-header></lg-header>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

**header.component.html**

```html
<div style="float:right; padding-right:30px">
  <button id="button-logout" mat-button (click)="toggleLanguage()">
    <img width="27" height="17" style="margin-right: 10px;" src="./assets/images/{{flag}}_Flag.png"/>
    <span>{{languageName}}</span>
  </button>
</div>
```

**header.component.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

import { IUser, IUserCourses } from '../users/user';
import { UserProgressService } from '../users/user-progress.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'lg-header',
  templateUrl: './header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./header.component.sass']
})
export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit {
  // variables for laungage
  language: number;
  languageName: string;
  flag: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
              private router: Router,
              private userProgressService: UserProgressService) {
                userProgressService.connectUser();
                this.getUpdatedLanguageAndFlag();
              }

  // get from service updated data from backend and localStorage
  getUpdatedLanguageAndFlag() {
    this.language = this.userProgressService.getLanguage();
    this.flag = this.userProgressService.getFlag();
    this.languageName = this.userProgressService.getLanguageName();
  }

  ngOnInit() { }

  // change laungage
  toggleLanguage(){
    this.userProgressService.changeAppLanguage();
    this.getUpdatedLanguageAndFlag();
    if (this.router.url == '/courses') {
      // I need to trigger here getCourseListByLanguage in course-list from here
    }
    else
      this.router.navigate(["/courses"]);
  }
}
```

**user-progress.ts**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, groupBy } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { LocalStorage } from '@ngx-pwa/local-storage';

import { UserService } from './user.service';
import { IUser, IUserCourses } from './user';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class UserProgressService {
      private user: IUser;
      private errorMessage: string;
      private language: number;
      private flag: string;
      private languageName: string;

      constructor(private userService: UserService) { }

      // get user from local store
      connectUser() {
        this.user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));
        this.language =+ localStorage.getItem('language');
        this.flag = localStorage.getItem('flag');
        this.languageName = localStorage.getItem('languageName');
      }

      getUserName() {
        return this.user.name;
      }

      getLanguage() {
        return this.language;
      }

      getLanguageName() {
        return this.languageName;
      }

      getFlag() {
        return this.flag;
      }

      // determine flag and language name depends on language value
      setFlagLanName() {
        if (this.language == 0) {
          this.flag = "UK";
          this.languageName = "English";
        }

        else {
          this.flag = "FR";
          this.languageName = "French";
        }

        localStorage.setItem('languageName', this.languageName);
        localStorage.setItem('flag', this.flag);
      }

      // manage toggle action
      changeAppLanguage() {
        if ( this.language == 0 )
            this.language = 1;

        else
            this.language = 0;

        this.setFlagLanName();
        this.updateBackendLanguage(this.language);
      }

      // update language in backend
      updateBackendLanguage(lan: number) {
        this.userService.updateLanguage(this.user.id, lan).subscribe(
          () => { this.getUserFromBackend(); },
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
      }

      // update user after changes - call the backend again for GET
      getUserFromBackend() {
        this.userService.getUser(this.user.id).subscribe(
          user => {
            this.user = user;
            this.language = user.language;
            localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(this.user));
            localStorage.setItem('language', this.user.language.toString());
          },
          error  => this.errorMessage = <any>error
        );
      }
  }
```

**user.service.ts**

```js
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse, HttpHeaders, HttpParams } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
import { Observable, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, groupBy, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { IUser, IUserCourses } from './user';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' })
};

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  private url = environment.educationBE_url+'/users';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {  }

  // Get Single user by id. will 404 if id not found
  getUser(id: number): Observable<IUser> {
    const detailUrl = `${this.url}/${id}` + '.json';

    return this.http.get<IUser>(detailUrl)
        .pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
  }

  // update user preference for language view
  updateLanguage(user_id: number, language: number) {
    const userUrl = `${this.url}/${user_id}` + '.json';
    let body = JSON.stringify({language: language});

    return this.http.patch(userUrl, body, httpOptions)
      .pipe(
        tap(_ => console.log(`updated user ${user_id} with this entry: ${language}`)),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }

  // // Handle Any Kind of Errors
  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse) {

    // A client-side or network error occured. Handle it accordingly.
    if (error.error instanceof ErrorEvent) {
      console.error(`Error: ${error.error.message}`);
    }

    // The backend returned an unsuccessful response code.
    // The response body may contain clues as to what went wrong.
    else {
      console.error(`Error Code: ${error.status}\nMessage: ${error.message}`);
    }

    // return an Observable with a user-facing error error message
    return throwError(
      'Something bad happend; please try again later.');
  }
}
```

**course-list.ts**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, Routes } from '@angular/router';

import { ICourse } from '../course';
import { CourseService } from '../course.service';
import { UserProgressService } from '../../users/user-progress.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'lg-course-list',
  templateUrl: './course-list.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./course-list.component.sass']
})

export class CourseListComponent implements OnInit {
  courses: ICourse[] = [];
  errorMessage: string;

  // variables for laungage
  language: number;
  languageName: string;
  flag: string;
  
  // the courses we display in html file
  coursesByLanguage: ICourse[] = [];

  constructor(private courseService: CourseService,
        private userProgressService: UserProgressService,
        private route: ActivatedRoute,
        private router: Router) {
          userProgressService.connectUser();
          this.getUpdatedLanguageAndFlag();
        }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCourseList();
  }

  getUpdatedLanguageAndFlag() {
    this.language = this.userProgressService.getLanguage();
    this.flag = this.userProgressService.getFlag();
    this.languageName = this.userProgressService.getLanguageName();
  }

  // Get list of courses from service
  getCourseList() {
    this.courseService.getCourses()
      .subscribe(
        courses => {
          this.courses = courses;
          this.getCourseListByLanguage();
        },
        errorMessage => this.errorMessage = <any>Error
      );
  }

  // get from courses only the relavent ones
  getCourseListByLanguage() {
    this.getUpdatedLanguageAndFlag();
    this.coursesByLanguage = this.courses.filter( course => course.language == this.language);
  }
  
  
  // change laungage
  toggleLanguage(){
    this.userProgressService.changeAppLanguage();
    this.getCourseListByLanguage();
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a timing issue.

Normally, the recommendation is to subscribe in the UI, as close to the event needing the result of the subscription.

Try moving the subscribe here (pseudo code):

```
  toggleLanguage(){
    this.userProgressService.changeAppLanguage().subscribe(x => {
      this.getUpdatedLanguageAndFlag();
      this.router.navigate(["/courses"]);
    };
  }
```

By putting the following two functions within the subscribe, you'll ensure they are not executed until the language is actually changed.

NOTE: For this to work correctly, you need your `.changeAppLanguage()` method to return an observable. So this code also needs to change (pseudo code):

```
  changeAppLanguage(): Observable<any> {
    if ( this.language == 0 )
        this.language = 1;

    else
        this.language = 0;

    this.setFlagLanName();
    return this.userService.updateLanguage(this.user.id, this.language);
  }
```

BIG NOTE: None of this code was syntax checked as there was no provided stackblitz with the code.

The general idea is that your services should not be subscribing. They should instead be returning an Observable. The component code should then subscribe. Any code that needs to be executed *after* the subscription emits a value would be *within* that subscribe.

That will help ensure that your processes occur in the correct sequence.

Comment: I tried to do that but I got this error:  ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined

Comment: Yea, without a stackblitz I don't have a way to run this so can't get the syntax exact for you. See my further notes above.

Comment: I'll try to upload to stackblitz. I only need to subscribe the language because it's the only thing I get from the backend. the flag and languageName I determine based on the language. Language contains 0 for English and 1 for French, flag is "UK" if language = 0 or "FR" if language = 1, languageName = English/French depended on language as well. So I need only observable for language? but language is a string so I don't know how to implement it

Comment: user-progress.service is not like the usual service that doing HttpClient requests, it's main purpose to be a bridge between components and user.service which calls the backend with HttpClient. user-progress.service calculate things like if a user watched a video or finished a quiz, and contains user observable and store in localstorage so every component have access to the latest updates

Comment: I understand the problem. It's working on all the pages except for course-list, because we already in the component, so it's not calling getCoursesByLanguage. I need to make the partial component trigger the start of the life cycle of course-list component or somehow call the function getCoursesByLanguage in course-list from header. how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving all of the courses here:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCourseList();
  }
```

And when you get them, you immediately filter them:

```
  // Get list of courses from service
  getCourseList() {
    this.courseService.getCourses()
      .subscribe(
        courses => {
          this.courses = courses;
          this.getCourseListByLanguage();
        },
        errorMessage => this.errorMessage = <any>Error
      );
  }

  getCourseListByLanguage() {
    this.getUpdatedLanguageAndFlag();
    this.coursesByLanguage = this.courses.filter( course => course.language == this.language);
  }
```

So now `courses` is filtered to only those for the specific language: English1, English2, English3, etc.

Then you then later call `toggleLanguage` and re-filter the courses.

```
  toggleLanguage(){
    this.userProgressService.changeAppLanguage();
    this.getCourseListByLanguage();
  }
```

But at this point, `courses` is already the filtered listed, so you can't re-filter them to another language.

One way to solve this is to retain the list of all courses separate from the filtered courses.

So something like this:

```
  courses: ICourse[] = [];
  allCourses: ICourse[] = [];
```

Then set it here:

```
  getCourseList() {
    this.courseService.getCourses()
      .subscribe(
        courses => {
          this.allCourses = courses;    // Set all courses here
          this.getCourseListByLanguage();
        },
        errorMessage => this.errorMessage = <any>Error
      );
  }
```

Then filter into the `courses` variable.

```
  getCourseListByLanguage() {
    this.getUpdatedLanguageAndFlag();
    this.coursesByLanguage = this.allCourses.filter( course => course.language == this.language);
  }
```

Now you are always filtering the full list of all courses into only those for the specific language in the `courses` property.

Does this work?